# vEthernet (External) - Network Adapter Unplugged - Host OS not Guest VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, hyper-v, hypervisor

I'm testing moving from VMWare Workstation to Hyper-V and I'm having a hard time with getting networking working. I use a pretty simple setup, all my VM's should have access to LAN and WAN. Every other hypervisor has just worked OOB with default settings...

So far I have tried the following:

1. Creating Internal and External Virtual Switches with bridged connections to Ethernet NIC.
2. Switching from Network Adapter to Legacy Adapter.

It should be noted that the VM worked fine in VMWare Workstation so the configurations should be fine inside the guest VM which is Ubuntu 14.04 Server x64.

I believe what I want is a "External Adapter" which is bridged/shared with my main OS and Ethernet NIC, but when I look in adapters, it shows cable unplugged which leads me to think there is a problem with configuration. Any help getting my networking up would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is absurd, but I figured it out. On my TOWER which has a PCI WiFi/BT Nic (AC 7820), **the default switch was set to use the WiFi NIC and CAN'T BE CHANGED. Also, the default for new Virtual Switches was to use the WiFi NIC.** I didn't even think about it as I never use the WiFi, I got it for the Bluetooth, but as soon as I switched it on the newly created External NIC I had LAN and WAN Access.

Pretty Rediculous IMO to have a Hypervisor use the WiFi NIC as default over Ethernet... First steps back in Hyper-V aren't going great, but I think in the end it will suit my needs better than workstation. I'm mostly after the Auto-shutdown and Auto-startup feature which Workstation doesn't have and required scripts which sometimes worked.

[image]
[image]